# Outputting posts by tilte with wp_Query trouble

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Hello i am a trying to get this wp_query loop work but getting error that endwhile unexpected though another similar lopp is fine to output recent news. Please advice. First loop is designed to output posts from "news" category.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE)
add_shortcode( 'faq_all', 'FAQ_all_function' );

function FAQ_all_function( $atts ) { 

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
   'category_name' =>'FAQ',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'title',
) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ob_start(); ?>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 faq"><?php
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) ; $query->the_post();
?>
<article><h5><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">  the_title()  </a></h5>
<div class="post-text">  the_content()   <br>
<div class="inner-height collapse" id="<?php the_ID() ?>"></div>
<div class="inner-height-long collapse" id="<?php the_ID() ?>"></div>
<button class="btn transparent" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php  the_ID()  ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="<?php  the_ID()  ?>"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>Открыть полность</button>
</div>
    </article><?php
    ?>     
 </div>  <?php 
 endwhile;  ob_get_clean(); wp_reset_postdata(); 

}
}
```

This is working loop which outputs frequently asked question category correctly. You may check both loops as working examle but second on which is based on wp->query requset to wp database is fully workable
The outputing is based on buffering fragment of php document and printing it out.

```
add_shortcode( 'faq1', 'FAQ_function1' );
function FAQ_function1( $atts , $faq1) {
/*start buffering content with nulled variable t the start of the loop*/
$faq1=null;
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
       'category_name' =>'FAQ',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
            'cat' => '3',
        'orderby' => 'title',
    ) );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ob_start();
?>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12"> 

            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) :static $counter = 0; $query->the_post();
$count = $query->post_count;
if ( $counter  > ($count/2)):
 ?>
 <article>
                <h5 href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
<div class="post-text"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </article>

    <?php endif;
          $counter++;   
           endwhile; ?> </div> <?php  return ob_get_clean();
/*start buffering content with nulled variable of the start of the loop. Finished with content - outputting. */

         wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


    <?php 

}
```

Maybe it is a missed brasket but have a sore in eye to see what is inorrect:

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
add_shortcode( 'faq_all', 'FAQ_all_function' );

function FAQ_all_function( $atts ) { 

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
   'category_name' =>'FAQ',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'title',
) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ob_start(); ?>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 faq"><?php
    while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
?>
<article><h5><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php  the_title();  ?></a></h5>
<div class="post-text"><?php  the_content();   ?><br>
<div class="inner-height collapse" id="<?php the_ID() ?>"></div>
<div class="inner-height-long collapse" id="<?php the_ID() ?>"></div>
<button class="btn transparent" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php  the_ID()  ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="<?php  the_ID()  ?>"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>Открыть полность</button>
</div>
    </article><?php
    ?>     
 </div> 
 <?php 

endwhile; 
ob_get_clean();
wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
}
```

You needed to replace ';' with ':' in here:

```
while ( $query->have_posts() );    $query->the_post();
```

You also didn't wrap some functions in the php tag.

Comment: Thanks, Ali_k. I will try. As it is simply correct. Will let you know. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem, please check this as the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

`while ( $query->have_posts() ) ;`

I believe that should be a colon instead of a semicolon.

BTW: I strongly advise against using that syntax feature. Use curly brackets. They make reading code much easier (so does indentation, btw), every editor with basic syntax highlighting features can match them up, and they aren't a php-specific thing that people not familiar with php will trip over.

Comment: Sure it is.Somehow part of that code worked. I will replace to check it out.